# ggplot is not plotting correctly when run within a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotting below data using ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)

Data = data.frame('Date' = as.Date("2028-01-01") + 1:7,
                    'y' = c(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0),
                    'yLow' = c(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0) - 2.2,
                    'yUp' = c(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0) + 2.2,
                    'Pt1' = c(-1, 1.0, NA, NA, 4.0, 5.0, NA) + 3.2,
                    'Pt2' = c(NA, 1.0, 2, NA, 4.0, 5.0, NA) + 4.2)
Data

Variable_Pt = c('Pt1', 'Pt2')
Variable_Pt_Col = c('Red', 'Blue')

Plot = ggplot(Data, aes(x = Date, y = y)) +
        geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 0.8, color = "black") 

for (i in 1:2) {
    print(Data[, Variable_Pt[i]])
    Plot = Plot + geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = Data[, Variable_Pt[i]]), color = Variable_Pt_Col[i])
}

Plot
```

However surprisingly I dont see the points for the variable `Pt1`. Attached is a snapshot on what I see.

[image]

Can you please help me to understand what is incorrect in my code?

Below is my session info :

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.3.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] digest_0.6.27    withr_2.4.1      dplyr_1.0.4      crayon_1.4.1    
 [5] grid_4.0.3       R6_2.5.0         lifecycle_1.0.0  gtable_0.3.0    
 [9] magrittr_2.0.1   scales_1.1.1     pillar_1.4.7     rlang_0.4.10    
[13] farver_2.1.0     generics_0.1.0   vctrs_0.3.6      ellipsis_0.3.1  
[17] labeling_0.4.2   glue_1.4.2       purrr_0.3.4      munsell_0.5.0   
[21] compiler_4.0.3   pkgconfig_2.0.3  colorspace_2.0-1 tidyselect_1.1.0
[25] tibble_3.0.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could subset with `.data`

```
for(i in 1:2) {
   Plot <- Plot +
      geom_point(aes(x = Date,  y = .data[[Variable_Pt[i]]]),
         color =  Variable_Pt_Col[i])
 }


Plot
```

-output

[image]